# How to undo skip/take in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm skipping and taking from a `List` using LINQ and I'd like to **undo** the skipping and taking so that I can get the whole collection.

For example

```
List<int> aThousandObjects = Enumerable.Range(1,1000).ToList();

List<object> list = aThousandObjects;
int listOriginalLength = list.Count();
int take = 100;

for(int taken = 0; taken < Math.Ceiling((double) listOriginalLength / 100) * 100; taken += take)
{
    list = list.Skip(take);
    updateValues(list.Take(take));
}
```

Now I'd like this to somehow be true

```
list.Count() == listOriginalLength
```

So that I can do this

```
IEnumerable<object> newValues = list.Select(x => x.NewValue);
```

Without getting "no results"

[image: Enumeration yielded no results]

Comment: The question is unclear. Your code doesn't compile because `Skip` doesn't return a list but`IEnumerable<T>`. But apart from that, you have the original list already in  `aThousandObjects` .

Comment: Why don't you cache an original `IEnumerable` variable before applying `Skip`, `Take` or whatever?

Comment: Yes it seems unclear

Comment: that code won't compile, so...

Comment: In order to undo, just cache the original collection or retrieve it again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't unwrap a composed query except via nasty reflection to obtain the inner fields.

But: you can go back to the original:

```
IEnumerable<object> list = aThousandObjects;
// compose LINQ etc...

// undo!
list = aThousandObjects;
```

Every LINQ operation here composes by encapsulating one `IEnumerable<T>` inside another. If you snapshot **at any time** (by storing the current enumerable in a local etc): you can go back to that snapshot - you don't need to go back to the root list.

Comment: Love the exclamation mark in your comment. I don't know why but it made the undo seems so cheerful it made me giggle.

Comment: Also one need to ensure here, that `aThousandObjects` is immutable, e.g. it's not a "stream" or something like that. So it returns the same set of values every time it's traversed and cause no unacceptable side-effects or performance penalties.

Comment: @stop-cran well, in the code shown it isn't actually enumerated at all, so *nothing has happened yet* to *have* side effects (well, except the `Count()` at the very top; I'll grant you that one, but: `var originalCount = aThousandObjects.Count;` <== fixed!

Comment: @stop-cran: would be a good point if `aThousandObjects` would be `IEnumerable<Object>` instead of `List<Object>` which can't be a stream or query. Of course it's possible that this object is modified meanwhile, for example from another thread.